# Choose interface on pxe boot host

Tags: boot, server, pxe

I am trying to set up a PXE boot environment for Ubuntu 22.04 using IBM HS-22 blades at work. Most everything is going well except the HS-22 blades on boot will choose their USB interface to get a DHCP address from. Since this isn't connected to anything it responds quickest with a 169.x.x.x address and declares that it cant find my repo on the network. If I reboot over and over it will randomly work correctly at some point and pick up an IP on the eno1 interface and continue on with the install.
Is there a way to specify in the pxe config which interface to boot off of, or anyway to disable that USB in terface on the HS-22? I havent found either answer yet after a couple weeks of searching.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HS-22 blade IMM's Ethernet over USB interface can be enabled or disabled using the Advanced Management Module (AMM)'s web interface:

1. Navigate to the Service Processor's Ethernet over USB interface section on the blade configuration web page. The section lists all blades in the chassis which are capable of enabling and disabling the Ethernet over USB interface.
2. Select the checkboxes next to the blade(s) that you want to enable or disable.
3. Click the Disable button to disable the Ethernet over USB interface on the selected blades, or click the Enable button to enable the interface.

You may refer to [Prevent in-band access to the Integrated Management Module](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/prevent-band-access-integrated-management-module-ibm-bladecenter-hs22-type-7870#:%7E:text=The%20IMM%27s%20Ethernet%20over%20USB%20interface%20can%20be,click%20the%20Enable%20button%20to%20enable%20the%20interface.) for more information.

Comment: While the link can lead to a correct solution, link-only answers with minimum explanation can become unhelpful in case the linked content changes after a time. Since one of the main questions here was, *"Is there a way to ... disable that USB interface on the HS-22?"*, it would be better to include the actual steps in your answer. 
 Please see *[Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/902710)* for more details.

Comment: Excellent! that did the trick fr my blades. Thanks!